# this is undefined in Babel-compiled methods

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying to write a small webapp with React 0.13 and ES6 syntax. I'm using webpack and babel-loader to compile:

```
loaders: [
  { test: /\.js/, exclude: /node_modules/, loader: "babel-loader"}
]
```

I'm having trouble with the this variable inside methods, getting "this is undefined" in several places throughout my code. For example:

```
export class PanelEditor extends React.Component {
  ...
  update (){
    if (!this.isMounted())
      return;

    this.setState(this.getStateFromStore());
  }
  ...
}
```

The *this* variable should never be undefined under this conditions. However, I found that the problem might be the way Babel rewrites the code:

```
update: {
  value: function update() {
    if (!this.isMounted()) {
      return;
    }
    this.setState(this.getStateFromStore());
  }
},
```

In that way, it seems to me, the *this* variable refers to the object literal instead of the *class*. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's not actually the problem.  It's that `this` is undefined, because you're not binding the update function.

You can do this in the `constructor` or in render.  Most people do it in render.

```
<div onClick={this.update.bind(this)} />
```

Or (my preference), an arrow function which preserves `this`.

```
<div onClick={() => this.update()} />
```

Comment: (And for the real "why" is that when using the `class` syntax rather than `React.createClass` is that the React team decided to not provide a way for doing auto-binding with the new way: http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/01/27/react-v0.13.0-beta-1.html#autobinding)